# What does these FXAA settings do?

Tags: webgl, antialiasing

I been looking for a way to do anti-aliasing with deferred rendering with WebGL as my target platform. WebGL does not support multisampled FBOs. I found FXAA implmentations such as this https://github.com/mattdesl/glsl-fxaa/blob/master/fxaa.glsl and it has the following:

```
#ifndef FXAA_REDUCE_MIN
    #define FXAA_REDUCE_MIN   (1.0/ 128.0)
#endif
#ifndef FXAA_REDUCE_MUL
    #define FXAA_REDUCE_MUL   (1.0 / 8.0)
#endif
#ifndef FXAA_SPAN_MAX
    #define FXAA_SPAN_MAX     8.0
#endif
```

Im wondering what does these settings do and if I could tweak those settings to produce better results.

I have implemented FXAA with the default settings and I found the image quality to be unsatisfactory. Is there other anti aliasing techniques I could try given the limitations of webgl platform?

Comment: Supersampling would work albeit not very practical for limiting platforms.